# Changed Minecraft account name & now it says I'm not who I am

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just changed my name and when I got back onto minecraft it said I was using a totally different account. How can I change this back?

Comment: You can't undo this until the name you used is available and you have another name change. If the server you were on doesn't store your settings with UUID but does it by username then there is no way to fix it.

Comment: "it said I was using a totally different account" - what says this?

Answer (score 1):

Just log out and log in again. If *that* doesn't work, try https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638.